# Issues getting nginx to serve my flask app

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have a flask app that I would like to serve via a DO Droplet.
I have followed [How To Serve Flask Applications with Gunicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04)

This is my folder structure

```
root/ 
└── baseweb/
     ├── venv
     ├── app.py 
     └── app/ 
         ├── routes.py 
         └── templates/ 
             └── index.html
```

app.py looks like this

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I have created a baseweb service

```
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
Requires=project.sock
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/baseweb
Environment="PATH=/root/baseweb/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/root/baseweb/venv/bin/gunicorn --preload --timeout 120 --bind unix:/baseweb/baseweb.sock -m 007 --work

Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my nginx configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/baseweb`) - edited per arthur simas comment below

```
server {
  list 80;
  server_name baserank.net, www.baserank.net;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  }
}
```

When i simply run app.py using my venv, i can access my flask app directly via the IP

if I run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app` i can also access my app via the same IP.

But when i try to access via nginx (via the domain or the IP directly without running the app in console), i get timed out

I have spent hours trying to adjust settings, but i have no idea where this is going wrong - so any help is very much appreciated.

Edit 2023-02-17: Ngnix access.log

```
185.16.141.5 - - [17/Feb/2023:14:14:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "http://baserank.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
185.16.141.5 - - [17/Feb/2023:14:14:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "http://baserank.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
185.16.141.5 - - [17/Feb/2023:14:14:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "http://baserank.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
185.16.141.5 - - [17/Feb/2023:14:14:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "http://baserank.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
143.110.222.166 - - [17/Feb/2023:14:22:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

Comment: Does that need to be `--bind unix:/root/baseweb/baseweb.sock` instead?

Comment: If you go on the host when the service is launched, do you see the socket file being created?

Comment: You can also debug without nginx by curling to the socket file directly https://superuser.com/a/925610/426081

Comment: Can you show me what is in your nginx log? sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: @dms_quant can you please post the `error.log`?

Comment: can you post your gunicorn and nginx error logs

Comment: Have u tried to put your nginx conf into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/baseweb and /etc/nginx/sites-available/baseweb ?

Answer (score 6):

There could be multiple issues that lead to a 502.
I would first make sure that your nginx configuration is being used at all when accessing baserank.net by proxy_pass'ing to 127.0.0.1:5000:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name baserank.net www.baserank.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

Next if you see your Flask Installation, please check which user nginx is using by using:

```bash
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep user
# user www-data;
```

If you see something other than `root` here, it's most likely that nginx is unable to access the socket as it's inside the `/root` directory.

A better place to store the socket is `/var/run` but you're good as long as the user nginx is running as can access the socket:

```
/root/baseweb/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:/var/run/baseweb.sock app:app
```

And the corresponding nginx location conf:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/baseweb.sock;
}
```

If the nginx user can access the socket but you still get a 500 you should debug the socket using curl:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/baseweb.sock http://localhost/
```

I would suspect the socket being under /root/ is the main culprit here.
You can quickly debug this by setting nginx users to root as well (but switch it back after that quick test and fix permissions accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

your ngnix config is wrong. you don't use `root` directive for reverse proxying with nginx, but instead `proxy_pass`. the tutorial you've posted is right. the changes you should do:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain www.your_domain; # place here your website domain (optional directive)

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/root/baseweb/baseweb.sock;
    }
}
```

- `listen` tells were the nginx server should listen to requests. it could be only the `port` (`80`), `ip:port` (`68.183.68.148:80`), an unix socket (`unix:/var/run/nginx.sock`), etc...
- the `proxy_pass` directive acts as a reverse proxy, forwarding traffic to the provided URL.
- `root` is for serving static files.

read more at:

- [NGINX Module `ngx_http_core_module` - `listen`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)
- [NGINX Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)
- [NGINX Module `ngx_http_proxy_module` - `proxy_pass`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)
- [Serving Static Content](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

also, be sure to create the service in *systemd*, at the correct path location and check if its running `sudo systemctl status myproject` (or nginx would not be able to forward traffic to it)

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.


I tried updating the ngnix config, but unfortunately i still get the same error.


the systemctl status tells me the service is running with the following log:
Listening at: unix:/root/baseweb/baseweb.sock (172489)

Comment: try to check nginx logs to see the error causing the bad gateway. by default, nginx logs are located at `/var/log/nginx` (e.g. `/var/log/nginx/access.log`). feel free to post the relevant output on your original question as a code block, please

Answer (score 0):

According to your project service configuration, it seems that the project sock or socket file is missing in the service configuration. Generally located at `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Generally, in a service file, there are two variants of file that are required in order to run your flask app's first one is `project.service`, and the second one `project.socket`, `project.service` is connected with `project.socket`.

First, create `project.socket`. under the directory `/etc/systemd/system/`.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Flask App
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/project.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=socket.target
```

Second, create `project.service`. under the directory `/etc/systemd/system/`.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Flask App
Requires=project.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=username
Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/username/flaskapp
ExecStart=/home/username/flaskapp/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 flaskapp:flaskapp

Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After the configuration is done, reload the daemon by using `systemctl daemon-reload` and finally restart the service by `systemctl restart project`.

Additionally, you can reconfigure [Nginx reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) if needed, like `proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project.sock`;